# Quartz job not firing

Tags: java, servlets, properties, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I referred to a previous question, found at [Quartz properties does not trigger Quartz Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596957/quartz-properties-does-not-trigger-quartz-job) , and borrowed heavily from it (being a newbie to Quartz and all) but my job doesn't seem to be firing.

My `quartz.properties`:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore

#===================================================
# Configure the Job Initialization Plugin
#===================================================

org.quartz.plugin.triggerHistory.class: org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class: org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames: quartz-jobs.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound: true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval: 10
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction: false
```

My `quartz-job.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
version="1.8">

    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>myjob</name>
            <group>MYJOBGROUP</group>
            <description>Job to Test</description>
            <job-class>com.mpm.epick.enotify.EmailNotifier</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>my-trigger</name>
                <group>MYTRIGGER_GROUP</group>
                <job-name>myjob</job-name>
                <job-group>MYJOBGROUP</job-group>
                <cron-expression>* * * * * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>

</job-scheduling-data>
```

Parts I added in my `web.xml`:

```
<!-- added by ck -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
    <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<!-- end additions -->
```

The class file I wish to run, `EmailNotifier' (right now it's just a stub implementation):

```
package com.mpm.epick.enotify;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class EmailNotifier implements Job {

    public EmailNotifier() {}

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Cron executing ");
    }

}
```

So what I observe is that my scheduler can start/stop normally, as shown by the following debug lines:

```
INFO: QuartzInitializer: Scheduler has been started...
INFO: QuartzInitializer: Quartz Scheduler successful shutdown.
```

But on my console I don't see the debug line at all. I tried the log files but it wasn't there either.

Am I missing something to fire my job?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this could be because your cron expression is odd. I'm not sure what the intent is with "* * * * * ?" expression, but if you wanted it to fire every second you should probably use "0/1 * * * * ?". See http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06 for more information on building cron expressions.